# Header not vertically aligning

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have my [website](http://colourity.com/slide/Demo/demo.html) and if you scroll up you'll see that the header is just above the center line. I can't figure out how to get it to be the same as the purple one. Any ideas?

Code for header on green page:

```
 .main section.page3 h1 {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      font-size: 70px;
      letter-spacing: -1px;
      color: black;
    }
```

And on purple page:

```
 .main section.page2 > img {
      position: absolute;
      top: -300px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -1095px;
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at it in the developer tool and it looks like you just have to remove a few margins. They are on the `.page2 .page_container` element, and the the `.page2 h1` element:

```
.main section.page2 .page_container {
    margin-top: 240px;                 /* Remove this. */
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main section.page2 h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 150px;                 /* Remove this. */
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much. I've been playing with it for hours.